# Blazor SSR and notifications

Tags: blazor

I have a dotNET 8 Blazor SSR application. I want to display a notification when something goes wrong.
This is the code that works fine:

```
    public async Task Save() 
    {
        try
        {
            // await Task.Delay(1000);
            throw new NotImplementedException("hello world");
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _notificationService.Notify(ex.Message, NotificationLevel.Danger);
        }
    }
```

An error is thrown and the notification service is called. The notification is displayed on the screen. As soon as I add an async function (in this example Task.Delay, in reality a db call) the notification service is still called but the notification is not displayed. I don't understand why it's not displayed. The only thing that changed is an await async method. It is still the same error!?
So this is the code that doesn't work:

```
    public async Task Save() 
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            throw new NotImplementedException("hello world");
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _notificationService.Notify(ex.Message, NotificationLevel.Danger);
        }
    }
```

For completion my notification service:

```
public class NotificationService : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly object _errorEvent = new();
    private readonly EventHandlerList _events = new();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _events?.Dispose();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> Error
    {
        add => _events.AddHandler(_errorEvent, value);
        remove => _events.RemoveHandler(_errorEvent, value);
    }

    public void Notify(string errorMessage, NotificationLevel notificationLevel)
    {
        if (_events[_errorEvent] is not EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> handler) return;
        var eventArgs = new ErrorEventArgs(errorMessage, notificationLevel);
        handler?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Registered in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
```

And my notification component html

```
@if (_open)
{
    <div id="success" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>@Message</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My notification cs file:

```
public partial class Notification
{
    private bool _open;

    [Parameter]
    public NotificationLevel NotificationLevel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void Open()
    {
        _open = true;
    }
}
```

And where I use my component in my layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        <Notification @ref="_notificationReference" Message="@_errorMessage" NotificationLevel="@_notificationLevel" />
        @Body
    </main>
</div>
```

And my layout .cs file:

```
public partial class MainLayout
{
    [Inject]
    private NotificationService _errorNotification { get; set; }

    public Notification _notificationReference;
    private string _errorMessage;
    private NotificationLevel _notificationLevel;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        _errorNotification.Error += SetErrorNotificationListener;
    }

    private void SetErrorNotificationListener(object? sender, Services.ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        _errorMessage = args.ErrorMessage;
        _notificationLevel = args.NotificationLevel;
        StateHasChanged();
        _notificationReference.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still some pieces of the puzzle are missing.  Do you have a StateHasChanged() anywhere in the Notify code path?

Comment: I added StateHasChanged() after the _open=true; and now it works. But I don't understand why. Why don't I need the StateHasChanged() method when I'm not using async methods?

Comment: It shouldn't work with non-async either. Maybe some other side effect causes a re-render.

Comment: where is `Notification.Open()` invoked? Personally, my approach would be different. Register your layout on the notification service. When a notification was updated, invoke a registered event of some sort that executes `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged))` on your layout component.

Comment: I forgot to add my layout .cs file (I added it now in the original question). That is where I call my Open() method